# pa package in R - performance attribution

Tags: r

When i try to upload my own data set into  pa package I am not able to call a Brison method.  I have attached a screenshot. The package itself bundled with the data set "jan", "quarter" and "year", there is no problem in running the analysis using these data (jan) or data (year) but my own data "Sample.xlsx" didn't work in the same way. When I try to run I get the following error: Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'Sample' not found.

Can anyone help me to clean up my data.

Here is the code for the first 4 lines

data <-
structure(
list(
date = structure(
c(1420070400, 1420156800, 1420243200,
1420329600),
tzone = "UTC",
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
),
portfolio_return = c(0.0212, 0.019, 0.021, 0.03),
australian_equities_3 = c(0.01,
0.02, 0.01, 0.01),
domestic_fixed_interest_4 = c(0.02,-0.01,
0.02, 0.05),
cash_equivalents_5 = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03),
australian_equities_6 = c(0.28, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3),
domestic_fixed_interest_7 = c(0.32,
0.3, 0.3, 0.3),
cash_equivalents_8 = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4),
total_weight_9 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
benchmark_return = c(0.0175,
0.0215, 0.032, 0.0381666666666666),
australian_equities_11 = c(0.02,
0.01, 0.01, 0.00333333333333333),
domestic_fixed_interest_12 = c(-0.01,
0.02, 0.05, 0.08),
cash_equivalents_13 = c(0.04, 0.03, 0.03,
0.0233333333333333),
australian_equities_14 = c(0.25, 0.25,
0.25, 0.25),
domestic_fixed_interest_15 = c(0.35, 0.35, 0.35,
0.35),
cash_equivalents_16 = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4),
total_weight_17 = c(1,
1, 1, 1),
allocation_australian_equities = c(7.5e-05,-0.000575,-0.0011,-0.00174166666666667),
allocation_domestic_fixed_interest = c(
0.000824999999999999,
7.49999999999999e-05,
-9e-04,
-0.00209166666666667
),
allocation_cash_equivalents = c(0,
0, 0, 0),
selection_australian_equities = c(-0.0025, 0.0025,
0, 0.00166666666666667),
selection_domestic_fixed_interest = c(0.0105,-0.0105,-0.0105,-0.0105),
selection_cash_equivalents = c(-0.004,
0.004, 0, 0.00266666666666668),
interaction_australian_equities = c(-3e-04,
5e-04, 0, 0.000333333333333333),
interaction_domestic_fixed_interest = c(-0.000899999999999999,
0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015),
interaction_cash_equivalents = c(0,
0, 0, 0)
),
row.names = c(NA,-4L),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame")
)

Comment: Hi, it'll be much easier if you provide an xlsx / table with sample data and the same structure as your source file has.

Comment: Please do not provide a screenshot of your code. Copy and paste the code and use `dput()` to provide an example of your data in order to make it reproducible.

Comment: Greetings! As others have already mentioned, its usually helpful to provide direct code in your question and a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of sharing your data is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg